# Deleting table view row throws a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

When I try to delete a row from the table view using the code below I keep getting a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. Im using Swift (Not sure what to make of it) and am building a table view based application. I've been trying to delete a row all day and I'm just not getting anywhere with it. This should be simple task but Swift is making it impossible for me.

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        if let tv = tableView {
            if let ip = indexPath {
                tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([ip], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            }
        }
        // Delete the row from the data source
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

The error seems to be related to the AppDelegate file:

[image]

Comment: What does the console tell you?

Comment: @jsksma2 i don't understand half of the stuff it tells me but ends with the line libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Right, that `NSException` usually contains a message. Try and run the termination deep enough that it spits out the message.

Answer (score 3):

Are you also updating the data source that backs the table view? It can cause problems if the `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection)` method doesn't change its return value.